# How to create upload file using link in php

Tags: php, html

I want to create upload file using a link basically i want that user can upload file by using upload link

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: show your try code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Read these articles, [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Create a `html` form with `<input type="file" />`. Try this.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="attachment"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

In **PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['attachment'])){
  //TODO
{
```